# Delete all elements in an array corresponding to Boolean mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, slice

I have a Boolean mask that exists as 2-D numpy array (Boolean Array)

```
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

I also have a separate 2-D numpy array of values that is of the same dimensions as the Boolean mask (Values Array)

```
array([[ 19.189 ,  23.2535,  23.1555,  23.4655,  22.6795,  20.3295,  19.7005],
       [ 20.688 ,  20.537 ,  23.8465,  21.2265,  24.5805,  25.842 ,  23.198 ],
       [ 22.418 ,  21.0115,  21.0355,  20.217 ,  24.1275,  24.4595,  21.981 ],
       [ 21.156 ,  18.6195,  23.299 ,  22.5535,  23.2305,  28.749 ,  21.0245],
       [ 21.7495,  19.614 ,  20.3025,  21.706 ,  22.853 ,  19.623 ,  16.7415],
       [ 20.9715,  21.9505,  21.1895,  21.471 ,  21.0445,  21.096 ,  19.3295],
       [ 24.3815,  26.2095,  25.3595,  22.9985,  21.586 ,  23.796 ,  20.375 ]])
```

What I would like to do is delete all elements from the the array of values where the same location in the Boolean area equals `False`. Is there an easy way to do this?

The desired output for this example is:

```
array([[ 19.189 ,  23.2535,  23.1555,  23.4655,  22.6795,  20.3295,  19.7005],
       [ 20.688 ,  20.537 ,  23.8465,  21.2265,  24.5805,  25.842 ,  23.198 ],
       [ 22.418 ,  21.0115,  21.0355,  20.217 ,  24.1275,  24.4595,  21.981 ],
       [ 21.156 ,  18.6195,  23.299 ,  22.5535,  23.2305,  28.749 ,  21.0245]])
```

In this particular example, all the `False` values exist at the end of the the Boolean array, but this is not always the case and they can be randomly distributed. Therefore, I need a way of deleting any element from the values array in where the corresponding mask value equals `False` in the Boolean array

Comment: Will entire rows be True or False? Or will there be a mix?

Comment: `arr[mask]` makes such a selection.  The result will be 1d, since in general such a mask could select differing numbers of values each row.  In some cases you might be able to reshape the result into meaningful 2d array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For most purposes you could simply create a [`MaskedArray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html) which behaves as if these were "removed", that also allows to "remove" single elements from a column/row while keeping the dimensionality the same:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[ 19.189 , 23.2535, 23.1555, 23.4655, 22.6795, 20.3295, 19.7005],
                [ 20.688 , 20.537 , 23.8465, 21.2265, 24.5805, 25.842 , 23.198 ],
                [ 22.418 , 21.0115, 21.0355, 20.217 , 24.1275, 24.4595, 21.981 ],
                [ 21.156 , 18.6195, 23.299 , 22.5535, 23.2305, 28.749 , 21.0245],
                [ 21.7495, 19.614 , 20.3025, 21.706 , 22.853 , 19.623 , 16.7415],
                [ 20.9715, 21.9505, 21.1895, 21.471 , 21.0445, 21.096 , 19.3295],
                [ 24.3815, 26.2095, 25.3595, 22.9985, 21.586 , 23.796 , 20.375 ]])
mask = np.array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
                 [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
                 [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
                 [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
                 [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
                 [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
                 [False, False, False, False, False, False, False]])
marr = np.ma.MaskedArray(arr, mask=~mask)
marr
```

Gives:

```
masked_array(data =
 [[19.189 23.2535 23.1555 23.4655 22.6795 20.3295 19.7005]
 [20.688 20.537 23.8465 21.2265 24.5805 25.842 23.198]
 [22.418 21.0115 21.0355 20.217 24.1275 24.4595 21.981]
 [21.156 18.6195 23.299 22.5535 23.2305 28.749 21.0245]
 [-- -- -- -- -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- -- --]],
             mask =
 [[False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

In this case it would be also possible to just compress all rows that contain at least one masked element with [`np.ma.compress_rows`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ma.compress_rows.html#numpy.ma.compress_rows):

```
>>> np.ma.compress_rows(marr)
array([[ 19.189 ,  23.2535,  23.1555,  23.4655,  22.6795,  20.3295,  19.7005],
       [ 20.688 ,  20.537 ,  23.8465,  21.2265,  24.5805,  25.842 ,  23.198 ],
       [ 22.418 ,  21.0115,  21.0355,  20.217 ,  24.1275,  24.4595,  21.981 ],
       [ 21.156 ,  18.6195,  23.299 ,  22.5535,  23.2305,  28.749 ,  21.0245]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your mask will consist of rows which are either all `True`, or all `False`, then you can use `mask.all(axis=1)` and index:

```
In [116]: x
Out[116]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])

In [117]: x[mask.all(axis=1)]
Out[117]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate my comment:

```
In [33]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [34]: mask = ((arr+1)%3)>0
In [35]: mask
Out[35]: 
array([[ True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

`arr[mask]` is 1d, because in general this selection does not return a neat 2d array.

```
In [36]: arr[mask]
Out[36]: array([ 0,  1,  3,  4,  6,  7,  9, 10])
```

We can see this clearly with the masked array solution

```
In [37]: marr = np.ma.MaskedArray(arr,mask=~mask)
In [38]: marr
Out[38]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[0 1 -- 3]
 [4 -- 6 7]
 [-- 9 10 --]],
             mask =
 [[False False  True False]
 [False  True False False]
 [ True False False  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

`ma` compressed returns the 1d array

```
In [39]: marr.compressed()
Out[39]: array([ 0,  1,  3,  4,  6,  7,  9, 10])
```

With 8 terms I can reshape it to (4,2), but nothing involving 3.

You can mask whole rows or columns with various combinations of `any` or `all`.