# subsetting 2d numpy array and keeping rows consistent

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

I was wondering what the simplest method for doing the following is:

Suppose we have the following 2d arrays:

```
>>> a = np.array([['z', 'z', 'z', 'f', 'z','f', 'f'], ['z', 'z', 'z', 'f', 'z','f', 'f']])

array([['z', 'z', 'z', 'f', 'z', 'f', 'f'],
   ['z', 'z', 'z', 'f', 'z', 'f', 'f']],
  dtype='<U1')



>>> b = np.array(range(0,14)).reshape(2, -1)


array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13]])


>>> idxs = list(zip(*np.where(a == 'f')))

[(0, 3), (0, 5), (0, 6), (1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 6)]


>>> [b[x] for x in idxs]

[3, 5, 6, 10, 12, 13]
```

However, I would like to keep the structure that was there before with regard to the first index or rows - i.e. :

```
[[3, 5, 6], [7, 11]]
```

Is there a way to keep this structure easily?

Comment: That's a mix of length 3 and length 2 lists; it can't be a 2d array.

Comment: @hpaulj yes it would end up being a list of lists, it can't be a numpy array at the end

Comment: @Alexander I fixed the small errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a more complicated, but pure NumPy, solution:

1. Get the indices (in a flattened version of `a`) where it's an `'f'`.
2. Get the indices where a new row begins
3. Find the indices in the array from 1 which belong to one row
4. Split the array at these indices.

The code would look like this:

```
>>> indices = np.flatnonzero(a.ravel() == 'f')
>>> rows = np.arange(1, a.shape[0])*a.shape[1]
>>> np.split(b.ravel()[indices], np.searchsorted(indices, rows))
[array([3, 5, 6], dtype=int64), array([10, 12, 13], dtype=int64)]
```

A bit longer than the other solutions and I'm not sure if it will be faster <sup>1</sup>.

Although, personally, I would go with a list comprehension and a `zip`:

```
[b_row[a_row] for a_row, b_row in zip(a == 'f', b)]
```

It's much shorter and according to my timings quite performant.

---

Timing:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([['z', 'z', 'z', 'f', 'z','f', 'f']]*10000)
b = np.arange(a.size).reshape(-1, a.shape[1])

%%timeit

indices = np.flatnonzero(a.ravel() == 'f')
rows = np.arange(1, a.shape[0])*a.shape[1]
np.split(b.ravel()[indices], np.searchsorted(indices, rows))
```

> 123 ms ± 8.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

```
%timeit [b[i][a[i] == 'f'] for i in range(len(a))]
```

> 162 ms ± 14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

But a lot slower compared to [my suggestion at Psidoms answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766936/subsetting-2d-numpy-array-and-keeping-rows-consistent/45767114#comment78492566_45766989):

```
%timeit [b_row[a_row] for a_row, b_row in zip(a == 'f', b)]
```

> 44.9 ms ± 1.93 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for` loop:

```
[b[i][a[i] == 'f'] for i in range(len(a))]
# [array([3, 5, 6]), array([10, 12, 13])]
```

Comment: or with `zip`: `[b_row[a_row == 'f'] for a_row, b_row in zip(a, b)]`. You could even go a step further and do the comparison outside of the loop: `[b_row[a_row] for a_row, b_row in zip(a == 'f', b)]` (that could be a bit faster).

Comment: @MSeifert Nice thought on the second option. I can see a speed up there.

Answer (score 1):

```html
a = np.array([['z', 'z', 'z', 'f', 'z','f', 'f'], ['z', 'z', 'z', 'f', 'z','f', 'f']])

b = np.array(range(0,14)).reshape(2, -1)

idxs = list(zip(*np.where(a == 'f')))


c=[[],[]]
for x in idxs:
    c[x[0]].append(b[x])

print c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [89]: idx = np.where(a == 'f')
In [90]: idx
Out[90]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32),
 array([3, 5, 6, 3, 5, 6], dtype=int32))
```

We can apply the `where` tuple to select items in `b`:

```
In [93]: b[idx]
Out[93]: array([ 3,  5,  6, 10, 12, 13])
```

Equivalently apply the boolean mask:

```
In [94]: b[a == 'f']
Out[94]: array([ 3,  5,  6, 10, 12, 13])
```

`np.argwhere` takes the transpose of `where`, producing a 2d array like your `idxs`.

```
In [95]: np.argwhere(a == 'f')
Out[95]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [0, 5],
       [0, 6],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 5],
       [1, 6]], dtype=int32)
```

As noted in [Delete all elements in an array corresponding to Boolean mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45748061/delete-all-elements-in-an-array-corresponding-to-boolean-mask), we can't, in general, select elements with a mask, and retain some sort of 2d structure.  In selected cases we can reshape the 1d result into something meaningful.

```
In [96]: b[idx].reshape(2,-1)
Out[96]: 
array([[ 3,  5,  6],
       [10, 12, 13]])
```

An easy way to collect these values on a row by row basis, and allowing for differing size results in each row, would be to iterate:

```
In [100]: [j[i=='f'] for i,j in zip(a,b)]
Out[100]: [array([3, 5, 6]), array([10, 12, 13])]
In [101]: [j[i=='f'].tolist() for i,j in zip(a,b)]
Out[101]: [[3, 5, 6], [10, 12, 13]]
```